# Mockito is getting a 404 when doing a "perform()" on my spring controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have a controller that works from a web browser when I run the Spring application. But when I run it with Mockito in a test, it throws a 404.

```java
@RestController
public class TestController {

    @GetMapping("/getproduct/{id}")
    public String getProduct(@PathVariable("id")  String productId)
    {
        if ( productId.equals("1") )
        {
            return "OK";
        }
    }
}
```

Test:

```java
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class MockitoApplicationTests {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Test
    public void testGetProduct() throws Exception{

        //Testing a correct product
        mockMvc.perform(
            get("/getproduct/1")
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        )
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andExpect(content().string(equalTo("OK")));
    }
}
```

Comment: Where did you configure your controller's use in your test? I don't think the auto configure can work without specifying your controller class to use somehow....  Also nothing here uses Mockito, FWIW

Comment: If it is just testing controller slice of the application, you should annotate your test class with **@WebMvcTest(TestController)**, not with **@SpringBootTest**